# Any finite abelian group of Möbius transformations is either isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ or is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, mobius-transformation

I want to solve the following question

Show that if a non-trivial element of $\mathcal{M}$ has finite order, then it fixes precisely two points in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$. Hence show that any finite abelian subgroup of $\mathcal{M}$ is either cyclic or isomorphic to $C_{2} \times C_{2}$.

**My Proof**: I managed to do the first part by using the fact that there are three conjugacy classes, meaning that either all,1 or 2 elements are fixed. Since we are dealing with an non identity element, it follows that either 1 or 2 elements are fixed. Then writing out the mobius transforms in matrix forms in some convenient basis and abusing the fact that the order is finite, we get that the only possibility is that we have only two fixed points.

The second part of the question is where I am having issues. I was able to prove that if $f,g \in H$, where $H$ is the subgroup in question, then $f$ and $g$ fix the same two elements, or interchanges them (just by looking at the fact that it is abelian). Using the fact that it has finite order I was also able to prove that each element has order $2$. But here is where I am stuck. I know that I have to show that for any other $h \in H$, we have that
$$
h \in \langle f,g \rangle
$$
but I can't seem to prove that. I tried

- Using the abelian property to show that $fh=hf$ and $gh=hg$ fix what $h$ can be and then go by contradiction with the size of the group and Lagrange's theorem, but to no success
- I tried using matrices and matching coefficients but that again did not work.
- I tried using cosets, by noting that $H$ must have an order that is a power of $2$ but again to no success.

Any ideas as how to proceed?

**Edit + Message to the moderators:** My question is not the same as the other one as the techniques and method used in the other question have not been covered in my course. This is a question from a first year course on group theory from the University of Cambridge.

Comment: @DietrichBurde , I just did so. Thank you for reminding me to fix that.

Comment: Please add a little more context: What is $\mathbb C_\infty$? And what is a Möbius map?

Comment: Perhaps $\mathbb C_\infty$ is a typographical error for $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the unclarity @LeeMosher . The former is meant to be the extended complex plane and Mobius map is just a Mobius transformation

Comment: Surely wlog we can suppose $f$ has fixed points $0$ and $\infty$ and sends $1$ to $\lambda$. Now if $g$ swaps $0$ and $\infty$ and has fixed point $1$ wlog we calculate and get $f(z)=-z$, $g(z)=1/z$. Now what can commute with these?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am probably wrong but I think there is too much loss of generality (for me) here. Moreover, I do not understand why does $g$ need to be in this set. Could you possibly be a bit more general?

Comment: It is not necessary that each element in $H$ has order $2$, for example take $f: z \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: @Zerox the Mobius transform that you have given has infinite order. Here we are considering only ones with finite ones.

Comment: It has order $3$, not infinite order. If you don't like that just simply take $f: z \mapsto iz$ which has order $4$.

Comment: HI, apologies for the confusion. Something wierd is going on. We either have $H$ cyclic or being the direct product of two realisations of $C_2$, thus considering $H$ not cyclic, we must have that every element must have order 2. Something has gone wrong here. Maybe the exams you have given above can not exist in a finite non-cyclic group? Any thoughts/ideas would be really appriciated.

Comment: Considering the non-cyclic case: Suppose $h \in H$ commutes with $f$ and $g$, then $h$ must fix/swap the fixed points of $f$ and fix/swap the fixed points of $g$. Since $g$ swaps the fixed points of $f$, the fixed points of $f$ and $g$ is a set of $4$ points, so the image of these $4$ points under $h$ is determined. Use the $3$-transitivity of Mobius transformations to show that $h \in \langle f,g \rangle$.

Comment: Hi @Zerox thank you for the comment. I am not quite convinced by your answer. You seemed to have assumed that $g$ always swaps the fixed points, however, this need not be true. What about the cases where $f$ and $g$ fix the same points?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756280/how-to-find-all-abelian-subgroups-of-möbius-transformations?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-trivial finite abelian subgroup of the Mobius group. Let $f\in A$. You have proved that $f$ has exactly two fixed points. As the Mobius group is $3$-transitive on the projective line $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ we may assume (by conjugating by a suitable element of the Mobius group) that the fixed points of $f$ are $0$ and $\infty$.

Now any element of the Mobius group fixing exactly $0$ and $\infty$ has the form $z\mapsto \lambda z$. If all the non-trivial elements of $A$ fix exactly these two points then each is of the form $z\mapsto \lambda z$ where $\lambda$ is by the finiteness a $k$-th root of unity for some $k$, so $A$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ and so clearly cyclic.

So suppose now that we have $f\in A$ of the form $z\mapsto \lambda z$, and also some $g$ which does not have fixed points $0$ and $\infty$. You have shown that $g$ swaps $0$ and $\infty$, and so $g$ is of the form $z\mapsto \mu/z$. Using the fact that $fg=gf$ we have that $\lambda=-1$. The same will be true for any other non-trivial element of $A$ with fixed points $0$ and $\infty$; it will be $z\mapsto\lambda' z$ and then $\lambda'=-1$.

Suppose that $g'$ is another element of $A$ swapping $0$ and $\infty$. It will be of the form $z\mapsto\mu'/z$. Using the fact that $gg'=g'g$ we find that $\mu'=\pm\mu$.

Hence if $A$ is not cyclic it consists of $\{z\mapsto z, z\mapsto -z, z\mapsto\mu/z, z\mapsto-\mu/z\}$, a copy of the fours-group $C_2\times C_2$.